# How do i handle the creation of mock for service class and carrying out the test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock

It gets tricky when it gets to method remove one from my controller  below when trying to test

```
@RequestMapping(value="/remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String remove(
        @ModelAttribute("id") String id, Model model
) {
    bookService.removeOne(Long.parseLong(id.substring(8)));
    List<Book> bookList = bookService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("bookList", bookList);

    return "redirect:/book/bookList";
}
```

And my test starts with mock injections in my before test method below

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    bookService = createMock(BookService.class);

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bookController, "bookService", bookService);

    userRepository= createMock(UserRepository.class);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bookController, "userRepository", userRepository);

    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(bookController)
            .setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter())
            .build();
}
```

And finally the test, trying to delete a book, not getting it to write. How do I continue?

```
@Test
public void bookRemoveTest() throws Exception {
   securityService.autologin("admin", "admin");

    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(1L);

    expect(bookService.removeOne(anyObject( class));).andReturn(book);

    replay(bookService);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc
            .perform(post("/book/remove")
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    String controllerResult = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
 }
```

Where did go wrong and how do I make this test work?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either targetObject or targetClass for the field must be specified

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:84)
    at com.admintest.controller.BookControllerTest.setUp1(BookControllerTest.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
```

Comment: here is what is wrong @Stephen

Comment: updated check now

Answer (score 16):

I know it's been asked a while ago but maybe it will help someone:

I had that error when I forgot to put @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) on top of my test class.
If you don't specify it, then mocks don't get created and you are trying to call ReflectionTestUtils on non initialized object.

Comment: I encountered this also when the object on which I was trying to make reflection was not yet initialized.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me. Appart from what I expect to be a typo in `expect(bookService.removeOne(anyObject( class));).andReturn(book);`.

Can you please tell us what's wrong? What's the exception and stack trace? Also, do we agree that the `bookController` is created by calling `new BookController()`?

Comment: it means your `bookController` isn't initialized before using `ReflectionTestUtils.setField`. So it's null